# Detect Polyethylene

Tags: analytical-chemistry, identification

How can we detect polyethylene from a distance?

The method should be mobile as I am thinking of employing it a mobile robot.

I have no idea about it.

Any suggestion or external link would be welcomed.

Comment: It looks problematic at best. There are many types of PE; also it would be very hard to discern if it's not PP for example.

Comment: Cross posted to [Robotics](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/q/6990/37).

Answer (score 3):

There is a growing literature on using [near-infrared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Near-infrared_spectroscopy) (NIR) [hyperspectral imaging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperspectral_imaging) (HSI) to detect a variety of materials, including plastics.  [Here's one example](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0921344912000080) that focuses on resolving polyethylene from the very similar polypropylene using NIR HSI.

Comment: Are they avialable in the market?

Comment: When I google for hyperspectral imager, many different companies selling products come up.  Resonon, Bayspec, Imec, etc. etc.  Depending on the setup, I'd expect a very basic camera to be $15000 to $30000 or more.